# How to make an array created inside a loop work outside from it?

Tags: java

I'm doing a java project to test different sorting algorithms and it is needed to use different typed of vector.

I determine the type of the vector whithin the code, so I need to declare it inside a loop. This is generating an error because of the array's scope. Is there anyway to make something similar or solving this error?

I'm on eclipse 2020, here is the code that is generating the error:

```
if(TypeOfVector(desorganized) == -1) {
    int[] organizedVector = PassingToIntVector(desorganized);}
if(TypeOfVector(desorganized) == 0) {
    float[] organizedVector = PassingToFloatVector(desorganized);}
if(TypeOfVector(desorganized) == 1) {
    double[] organizedVector = PassingToDoubleVector(desorganized);}
int organized = 0;
int duo;
int n = desorganized.size();
while(organized != n-1) {
    organized = 0;
    for (duo = 0; duo < n - 1; duo ++) {
        if(organizedVector[duo] > organizedVector[duo + 1]) {
            organizedVector[duo] = organizedVector[duo] - organizedoVector[duo +1];
            organizedVector[duo +1] = organizedVector[duo + 1] + organizedVector[duo];
            organizedVector[duo] = organizedVector[duo + 1] - organizedVector[duo];
        }
        else organized ++;
}
```

And here is an example of one of the PassingTo functions:

```
public float[] PassingToFloatVector(ArrayList<Object> list) {
        Object[] array = list.toArray();
        float[] desorganized = new float[list.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            desorganized[i] = (float) array[i];
        }
        return desorganized;
```

Comment: could you format your code before posting? it isn't readable

Comment: looks like you try to create vetorOrganizado dynamically to fit several types (int, float, double) its not allow in several if branches since there is no guarantee that one of them is created at all. search for 'java variables scope' for further instructions

Comment: Each `{ ... }` is a block and variables declared in that block are not visible outside of it. Hence the error. If you move `double[] vetorOrganizado` before the first `if`, it could work (I didn't try cause you didn't provide a [mcve]), but you would be treating everything as doubles, which may or may not be what you want. You could use a collection like `List<Number>` instead, and then `Collections.sort(...)`.

Comment: You could just sort your arrays directly after you have created them using Arrays.sort() but of course it depends on what are you going to do with the array afterwards if that helps.

Comment: If you wanted one variable the is either, float[], int[] or double[] you could declare it as Object, but then anytime you want to access it or use it you have to cast it back to the correct array type.

Comment: Also, since you're using Collections.swap which takes a list, you can use List<Float>, List<Integer> or List<Double>. Then you can declare your outer list as List<? extends Number> if you only want one type of number in it.

Comment: This casting is what I'm trying to do, the function PassingTo* convert the Objects into their respective type

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. Can you include your declaration of `desorganized` and at least one of your PassingTo... methods?

Comment: Ok, so what do you plan to do with `Collections.swap` that requires a List and not an array.

Comment: I can use an auxiliary variable and swap then manually

Comment: There, fixed the swap problem

Comment: I second @matt 's idea, the trouble with primitive array is it can not be cast from one to another. I guess you want to have a generic sorting algorithm that takes in all types of array and sorts their elements internally. But the input to that algorithm has to be some common interface among float[], int[], double[], which does not exist. When using lists, we can cast List<Float>, List<Double> , List<Integer> to List<Comparable>, so that a generic algorithm just needs to deal with Comparable elements inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue that you're asking about is scope. You need to declare your variable with scope to continue on.

```
if(TypeOfVector(desorganized) == -1) {
    int[] organizedVector = PassingToIntVector(desorganized);
}
if(TypeOfVector(desorganized) == 0) {
    float[] organizedVector = PassingToFloatVector(desorganized);
}
```

This would need to be changed because you're declaring your arrays within the if blocks and they will be lost once you leave the if block. ie They go out of scope.

```
int[] organizedVector;
if(TypeOfVector(desorganized) == -1) {
    organizedVector = PassingToIntVector(desorganized);
}
if(TypeOfVector(desorganized) == 0) {
    organizedVector = PassingToFloatVector(desorganized);
}
```

This will put `organizedVector` in a larger scope and you can use it after the if statements **but** you cannot assign it to a float[], so the second if statement will fail. Consider sticking with a `List<Integer>`, `List<Float>`, `List<Double>` which are all `List<? extends Comparable>`.

Then you can compare the elements, and swap them with collections.swap as necessary. Note that primitive arrays are not interchangeable. You'll have to write three different blocks of code to handle the three different array types.

Comment: He won't be able to do the comparison with List<? extends Number>. Maybe with List<Comparable> it will work.

Comment: @GreyFairer ahh, I see. I thought Number was also Comparable, but an Integer is a Number and a Comparable<Integer>.

Comment: yeah, I made a function that compares objects and I'm using it to adapt the algorithms